# How to make transparent white over most of the map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

Hi I want to make transparent google map like this...[image]

Please  tel me what can I do?

Comment: try this not tested: `((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getView().setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)`

Comment: yes, I tried this but not working.

Comment: you can see `setAlpha()` option available only into `Marker.setAlpha()`.

Comment: Marker.setAlpha() just change transparency for the markers.